# Adding field is my state is not working why?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Does someone know why do I have `names` without my adding `selected` field???
I'm can retrieve `names` from my api json (1) and I'm trying to modify it in order to get  my adding `selected` field (2).

```
  export default function Display() {
        ...
        const init = async () => {
            const { data } = await axios.post("").then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                return res.names.map((item) => {
                    return {
                        ...item,
                        types: item.types.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: true }))
                    };

                })
            })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            setNames(res.data.names)
        }

        useEffect(() => {
            init();
        }, [])

        const change = (id, value, all) => {
            setStandards((prev) =>
                prev.map((i) => {... }));
    };
    return (
        <>
            {selectionNames.map((item) => (...))}

        </>
    );
}
```

here is my json from my api (1):

```
{
    "names": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Description": "descr",
            "types": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "decription":"descr1",
                },
                ...
        ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I would like to have `names` (2):

```
{
    "names": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Description": "descr",
            "types": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "decription":"descr1",
                    "selected":true,
                },
                ...
        ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your `.then()` doesn't return anything, so you get a Promise that resolves to `undefined`. Destructuring will throw an error (which you should be able to see if you check your browser console), really you shouldn't be using the `.then()` at all here since you're using `await`. You are also returning `data.names.map()` and are not doing anything with this value. You need to call `setState()` with the mapped data, not return it. You also don't need to call `setState()` on `data.names` if you're going to overwrite it with the mapped data.

Comment: Init function looks to return the good result, but setNames is call with the original data and not with the formated data. Does it help you ?

Comment: @NickParsons, like that maybe `const init = async () => {const { data } = await axios.post(""); setNames(data.names); return data.names.map((item) => {return {...item,types: item.types.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: true })) }; }); }` like that maybe ?

Comment: @iDziDz I tried to modify my `const init` above, is it better ??

Comment: @ZPaulB you don't want to set names to `data.names` though. You want to set it to `data.names.map(...)`. There is no use in returning something from `init()` as you never use the return value.

Comment: @NickParsons, the thing is that I receive from my api `names`, and I want to modify slightly the content of `names` by adding this field `selected`. I wanted to call it `selectionNames` but using one sate is better i guess. And I'm using this `names` with added field `selected` in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what init should looks like according to me :

```
    const init = async () => {
    const data = await axios.post("").then(res => {
            return res.data.names.map((item) => {
                return {
                    ...item,
                    types: item.types.map((t) => ({ ...t, selected: true }))
                };
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });

        setNames(data);
    
}
```

Comment: This wont work because you are returning an array from the `.then()` callback, so the Promise you `await` will resolve to an array, so `data` will be `undefined`, setting `names` to `undefined`

Comment: The array is returned by the resolved promise and stored in data. Maybe I miss something but it should works

Comment: It's not working. The thing is that I receive from my api `names`, and I want to modify slightly the content of `names` by adding this field `selected`. I wanted to call it `selectionNames` but using one sate is better i guess. And I'm using this `names` with added field `selected` in the rest of the code.

Comment: Any error ? Can you log data before using setNames and show use the result please ?

Comment: @iDziDz, I get an empty array `names : [ ]` and after : typeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at Display.jsx:65:1 at async init (Display.jsx:64:1)`

Comment: Instead of returing data.names.map(...) store in a variable and log it inside the .then(). Then show the result

Comment: Yes I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

Comment: This error can't appeared just now, can you update the code in your post with the code you have currently and share the entiere error with the line which raise it, please

Comment: @nem0z, I've update the code in my question

Comment: Sorry just forgot how does axios works, you have to read res.data instead of res. I updated my code ;)